# Flask SQLAlchemy reflection ignoring most of tables on Redshift

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating the engine and the Metadata as follows

```
engine = create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://USER:PASS.region.com:5439/DBNAME')
metadata = MetaData(schema='SCHEMA')
metadata.reflect(engine, only=['orders', 'packages'])
Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare()
print(Base.classes.packages)
```

Yields `AttributeError: packages`, and `dir(Base.classes)` returns no attributes with that name, neither with the `orders` name. Taking the `only=['orders', 'packages']` off makes it reflect only a few random tables.

Now, when using the inspector that comes with native SQLAlchemy the table actually works ([link to documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/reflection.html#reflecting-all-tables-at-once)):

```
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
print(insp.get_table_names(schema='SCHEMA')) #this prints all tables as expected
packages_table = Table('packages', metadata)
insp.reflecttable(packages_table, None) #this reflects the table as expected
```

Is this a bug, or am I overlooking something here?

Thanks!

---

*Installed package versions:*

```
alembic                1.4.2
Flask                  1.1.2
Flask-Migrate          2.5.3
Flask-SQLAlchemy       2.4.4
psycopg2               2.8.5
SQLAlchemy             1.3.18
sqlalchemy-redshift    0.8.1
```

Comment: Do the "missing" tables have primary keys?

Comment: That's it! Only the ones with primary keys show up! Thank you snakecharmerb! Can you submit this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy's automap extension only reflects tables which have defined primary keys.

From the [note](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/automap.html#basic-use) in the docs:

> [...] for a table to be mapped, it must specify a primary key.