# Loading tables with foreign keys to sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a library management system and have the following tables in my database

```
books
students
loans
```

This is the output of the `Show Create Table loans` command

```
 CREATE TABLE `loans` (
  `book_no` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int NOT NULL,
  `issue_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `return_date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

The loans table references the student table and the books table but when i try to do an automap_base reflection i do not get the loans table. Why ?

Here is the cod I am using

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

Base = automap_base()
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://vedant:vedant@localhost/library_management')
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
Book = Base.classes.books
Student = Base.classes.students
Loan = Base.classes.loans
session = Session(engine)
```

Here is the error that i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 186, in __getattr__
    return self._data[key]
KeyError: 'loans'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\vedant\Library-Management-System\issue_books.py", line 17, in <module>
    Loan = Base.classes.loans
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 188, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: loans
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask SQLAlchemy reflection ignoring most of tables on Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404479/flask-sqlalchemy-reflection-ignoring-most-of-tables-on-redshift)

Comment: It does solve my question to some extent but i tried with other schemas and it reflected all the tables back